# to show nested sequence of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

We define $A,E:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ as linear map and $AS=\{Ax:x\in S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\}; A^{-1}S=\{x:Ax\in S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\}$

If we define $V_0=\mathbb{R}^n,\hspace{1cm}V_{i+1}=A^{-1}(EV_i)$,

how to show $\exists k\ni V_{k+1}=V_k\subseteq\dots V_1\subseteq V_0$

$x\in V_1=A^{-1}(EV_0)\Rightarrow Ax=Ey$ for some $y\in V_0\Rightarrow Ax\in AV_1\cap EV_0$, then  I can conclude $x\in V_0$ trivially as $V_0$ is the whole space!

$V_{i+1}\subseteq V_i$ in general? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show that $V_{i + 1} \subseteq V_i$ by induction by induction on $i$. For $i = 0$ this is clear, since $V_0 = \mathbb{R}^n$ by definition. Suppose it is true for $i \geq 0$, we must show it is also true for $i + 1$. But indeed
$$
V_{i + 2} = A^{-1}(EV_{i + 1}) \subseteq A^{-1}(EV_i) = V_{i + 1},
$$
where we use the induction hypothesis to show that $A^{-1}(EV_{i + 1}) \subseteq A^{-1}(EV_i)$.

The second statement that there is a $k$ such that
$$
V_{k + 1} = V_k \subseteq \ldots V_1 \subseteq V_0
$$
now follows from basic dimension theory.